# Prompt user for input and save that input for future iterations of the script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I built a script that runs on the users PC every minute via a scheduled task. The scheduled task gets created by a batch script that initially runs the PowerShell script but also schedules the task to run every minute.

I want the PowerShell script to prompt the user for certain variables (username, email address) and remember these variables each time it runs automatically until the user next manually runs the script.

I know I can do this:

```
$email= Read-Host 'What is your email address?'
```

But how do I make it save the input until it is next opened manually?

One idea I had was to have a batch script that schedules a task to run a batch script every minute. The batch script would then run the PowerShell script every time it is run and automatically and silently respond to the questions asked based on how the user edits the batch script. There has to be a better way than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, which would store the configuration in a file as XML under the users profile, unless that file already existed in which case it would load it:

```
$ConfigPath = "$env:userprofile\userconfig.xml"

If (test-path $ConfigPath){
    $Config = Import-Clixml $ConfigPath

}Else{
    $ConfigHash = @{
        email = read-host "What is your email address?"
        username = read-host "What is your username?"
    }

    $Config = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $ConfigHash
    $Config | export-clixml $ConfigPath
}
```

You then access the configuration settings as follows:

```
$Config.email
$Config.username
```

**Explanation**

- Defines a path to store the config (which uses the environment variable UserProfile)
- Uses `Test-Path` to check if the file exists
- If it does exist, uses the `Import-CliXML` cmdlet to load the file in to a PowerShell object in the variable `$Config`.
- If it does not exist, creates a hashtable which prompts the user for each configuration setting
- Uses `New-Object` to turn that Hashtable in to a PowerShell Object which is stored in `$Config`
- Writes `$Config` out to an XML file using `Export-CliXML` and stores it under the path defined in `$ConfigPath`.

Comment: i posted the whole script with what you wrote in my question. can you verify that i'm accessing the xml correctly as i've never done it like this before?

Comment: Yes you script looks like it should work to me. Try it and feedback if you get any errors or unexpected behaviour.

Comment: seemed to work just fine. xml was created and it ran multiple times with only asking me once for information. i can do the rest with a batch to launch and schedule tasks. Thank you very much for your assistance. much appreciated

Comment: I think `-BodyAsHtml` is a switch, you still also need to also use `-Body $Body`.